# How to filter words from a text file which don't have any vowel with Python?

Tags: python

Here's an example of  my listA.txt

```
bird
apple
hsjsnn
shs
skasu
ghsp
MHD
Nikes
```

after running the script I want my list to look like this

```
bird
apple
shs
skasu
MHD
Nikes
```

at least any of the one vowel (a,e,i,o,u) should be present in the word, if not it should remove the word. And the rules should apply to words having 4 or more letters.

I'm new to Python, so need some help.

I have a python program that removes words from a list based on the words mentioned in the program. I want one more with the opposite function, it should remove words that don't have vowels.

```
bad_words = ['abuse', 'spam']

with open('listA.txt') as oldfile, open('Final.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
            newfile.write(line)
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Sounds like homework. What did you try? You "bad words" example is one line away from the objective. Just change the condition to check vowels. You may define a list of vowels manualy.

Comment: `MHD` does not have vowels... and what happened to `shs`?

Comment: but MHD is 3 lettered and not 4 lettered or more to be filtered on vowels

Comment: @Simplecode Doesn't explain why shs is removed (or Nikes is added, for that matter)

Comment: @Jérôme, yes kind of homework. In my latest file, I want to remove words which don't have vowels, simple. (but not simple for me).

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I have corrected both lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex match to find vowels

```
import re

with open('listA.txt') as oldfile, open('Final.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if len(line) >= 4 and re.search('[aieou]', line, re.IGNORECASE):
            newfile.write(line)
```

Comment: So, it will remove all words which don't have a single vowel from list A? I'm going to test this now. Thanks

Comment: re.IGNORECASE will take care of both uppercase or lower case.

Comment: thanks for the code, it worked. I learned about re module today. I have a question, how to ignore anything after . (dot)?

Like in my list we have

brian.mate
nahshs.slate
hshshshs.kate

In above list there is a vowel after . (dot), how to make it work so that I don't regex anything after . (dot) with your same code?

Any ideas?

Comment: You could split the line on the dot, then check individual parts